# Why spring mvc scope variables require serialization?

Tags: spring-webflow

Recently we faced the issue of flowscope values not being set across the flow, but later after the investigation found that all the flowscope variables should be serialized ( my mistake i did not read the line from the spring webflow documentation - the line *"any objects stored in flow scope need to be Serializable"*

I feel this is kind of session information, in general we don't serialize session variable. Just curious why this serialization required for this spring webflow  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By forcing flow scoped objects to be Serializable, it provides the flexibility to safely store them anywhere - a database, on disk, etc - and then re-store them when returning to whatever flow state you were in.  While your particular server/environment might be a single machine, with every HttpSession (the default "backing" for spring web flow state) persisted in memory, others might have clustered/distributed web/app servers.